# Limit involving a factorial term

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to show that the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n!}{n^2}=0$ by using squeeze theorem.

Here we have $\frac{1}{n^2}\leq \frac{n!}{n^2}\leq g(n)$. I tried to find such a  function $g(n)$ but I failed. I know $n! \leq n^n$ but it does not help much because $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^n}{n^2} = \infty$.   Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {n!}{n^2} = +\infty$. (Note $n! > n(n-1)(n-2)$ for large $n$.) Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: Your edit does not address the problem. As it stands the task is impossible to complete because $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^2} \ne 0$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. There is a mistake in the question then.

Comment: $100\times 99\times 98$ is already much greater than $100^2$, and I haven’t even multiplied the rest of the terms $97\times96\times...\times 1$, which would make it even larger...